# Why does finite difference approximation method and RK4 method produce different result for an initial value problem?

Tags: boundary-value-problem, finite-differences, initial-value-problems, runge-kutta-methods

I'm trying to develop my knowledge about numerical methods. When studying finite difference methods in the boundary value problem I try to realize my code solving problem I came up with.

I start thinking about easy problem $u''=1, u(0)=0, u'(0)=0, x\in [0,1]$.
I took $h=0.1$, and used the second finite difference $$\frac{u_{i-1} -2u_i+u_{i+1}}{h^2}=1, u_0 = 0, \frac{u_1-u_0}{h}=0$$

Having solved the finite difference system on the grid with 10 nodes I noticed that my solution differs with analytical one sharply.
I realized then that I actually should have solved initial value problem instead of boundary value problem. Then I used RK4 for solving this problem and it gave good results.

I wonder why finite difference method produce this result with my first formulation of the problem? What is the problem I solved at the first time?

[image: Graphic Results with difference method]

Comment: $\dfrac{u_{i-1} -2u_i+u_{i+1}}{h^2}=1$ is going to lead to a quadratic solution and your blue line seems to meet this, looking like a parabola with roughly the correct curvature.  But it is in the wrong position, and in particular I cannot see what made you think it would go negative

Comment: My questions were why finite different method cannot solve initial value formulation of the problem I came up with and what have been solved by me actually when using finite difference method? As you can see the blue line is more like a solution of the boundary problem $u_0 = 0, u_n = 1$.

Comment: The problem is in the implementation. Check your code.

Comment: Here the [LINK](http://ideone.com/MOXNxB). You can execute my script and see my results for $u$. Choose Octave as programming language

Comment: You are mixing up concepts here: RK4 is also a finite difference method.

Comment: I tried to describe the problem with the best words I found. You can easily edit my question if it is not accurate enough. Anyway, this problem has been solved already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody is interested this question was fully investigated already.
My matrix for finite difference method was badly organized as [Eliad](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/212800/eliad) supposed, so it produced wrong result.

The finite difference method works for this problem well, it converges to the actual solution.
Full answer is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2113891/given-the-cauchys-problem-y-1-y0-0-y0-0-why-finite-differenc).